# SSL Certificate not working with letsencrypt

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt

We got SSL certificate from 123reg site. but in our server have letsencrypt installed for SSL so we are simply adding our certificate file insated of letsencrypt certificate file like
we save our certificate file (new) to /etc/letsencrypt/{site-name}.

we changed 000-default-le-ssl.conf file for certificate like below

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/safco
    ServerName example.com
   Redirect Permanent / https://example.com/
   SSLEngine on
     SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/shop/shop.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/shop/shop.pem
   Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
   SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/shop/intermediate.pem
   Redirect Permanent / https://example.com/

  </VirtualHost>
```

but it's also giving Your connection is not private.
but when i try to remove

```
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
```

from 000-default-le-ssl.conf file apache not restart.

how to install simple third pary SSL certificate in letsencrypt ?

Comment: Please include the contents of `options-ssl-apache.conf`, as well as the error message by running `systemctl status apache2.service` to determine probable solutions

Comment: systemctl status apache2.service
systemctl: command not found

Comment: Please provide more information: Operating System, Web Server + Version, contents of `options-ssl-apache.conf` so we have something to go on with. thanks

Comment: I found that letsencrypt working now with SSL certificate, issue was that we have more than one configuration file and have to change in all for SSL certificates.

Thank you